# C++ bad_alloc exception

Tags: c++, windows, exception

I am trying to catch the `bad_alloc` exception in order to prove that the destructors are used.

Here is my Object:

```
#include "Obj.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

Obj::Obj() {
d = new double[200000000];
}
Obj::~Obj() {
cout << "destroyed \n";
}
```

And the main method:

```
#include "Obj.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
Obj* ptr[1000000];
try{
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        ptr[i] = new Obj();
    }
} catch(bad_alloc){
    cout<<"EXCEPTION";
}
}
```

Instead of catching the exception, my program stops and tries to look for a solution online(Windows).
Why is this happening?

**EDIT**
I am getting now the exception, but I should prove that the destructor is used BEFORE the exception is thrown. How should I do that?

Comment: a solution online? what is that?

Comment: Solution named online in Visual Studio I guess.

Comment: @VJovic: On Windows, when programs cause certain classes of errors that Windows is able to detect, a dialog pops up asking if you want Windows to look for a solution online(perhaps the program has a bug and there is a known fix for it).

Comment: The `Obj` destructor will never be called by this program.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thank you for explaining what I meant.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @Jason I am using Eclipse for C/C++

Comment: A simpler way to get a bad_alloc exception: `/*#include <new>*/ throw std::bad_alloc();` perhaps?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Why will the destructor be never called? How can I make the program call it?

Comment: Your original question is answered.  Accept an answer, then make a new post.  Do not tag additional questions onto this post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem occurs before you even start dynamically allocating objects.  If you run the program with the debugger attached, you will see that the program is terminated due to a stack overflow.  Why?

```
Obj* ptr[1000000];
```

You cannot declare so large an object with automatic storage duration.  When `main` is entered, it attempts to allocate space on the stack for this object and fails to do so, causing a stack overflow structured exception to be thrown.  Your application does not handle this exception, so the runtime terminates the program.

Note, however, that the `Obj` destructor will never be called by your program.  When you dynamically allocate an object using `new`, you are responsible for destroying it using `delete`.  Since you do not ever call `delete` to destroy the objects you created, they are never destroyed.

If you were to use, say, a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Obj>>` instead (or, for that matter, just a `std::vector<Obj>`), you would see that the destructor would be called for every fully-created `Obj` object.

Comment: Thank you. I get now the exception. Please see the question update.

Comment: I thought the default stack allocation on windows was 1Mb, so in theory this should just fit...  Although possibly not with all the other stuff.

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Obj>>` is going to generate a compiler error for c++03, which most compilers still depend on.

Comment: @Benj:  I don't know what it is by default (that's one of those things where, _if you have to ask, you're doing it wrong,_ to paraphrase Raymond Chen).  That said, 1MB would be insufficient to store a contiguous array of one million four- (or eight-) byte pointers.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER:  Most _old_ compilers.

Comment: @James Apologies, forgot to multiply by 4, midnight is no time to be on SO, off to bed with me.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that you're attempting to store a very large array on the stack with your `ptr` array ... most likely your problem is that you've overflowed the default size of the stack allocated for your application before `operator new` is able to fail with an exception for being out-of-memory.

Comment: Allocating space for 1000000 then only using 1000 doesn't make much sense. Not to mention that each object will try to allocate 1.6GB (200M*8) in the `new` - I'm not sure you'll even be able to allocate one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I pasted all your code into a file, increased the integer constant a little, finished up the class definition for Obj, and reran your code with some debug.  On a 64-bit unix server, it properly prints out "exception" when it tries to execute the Obj constructor.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Obj {
Obj() {
d = new double[20000000000000000LL];
}
~Obj() {
cout << "destroyed \n";
}

double* d;
};

int main(){
Obj* ptr[1000000];
try{
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        ptr[i] = new Obj();
        cout<<"bah!"<<endl;
    }
} catch(bad_alloc){
    cout<<"EXCEPTION";
}
cout<<"Done."<<endl;
}

[jhumphreys@suoserv ~]$ g++ so2.cpp
[jhumphreys@suoserv ~]$ ./a.out
EXCEPTIONDone.
[jhumphreys@suoserv ~]$
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the exception on Windows?

Comment: I don't have a visual studio environment available to me - but I would assume if you ran the executable you created on a computer that didn't have visual studio and its debugging tools installed then you would see the output as you expected it when you wrote the program.  From memory I'm pretty sure that debugger feature is an add-in to windows that gets enabled once you start installing dev tools.

Comment: It has nothing to do with overprotectiveness.  When you run out of stack space, you run out of stack space.

Comment: Yeah, I removed that phrase since it was probably bogus.  I doubt he exhausted stack space though, his array of Obj*'s isn't horrendously big and everything else is heap-based.

Comment: @w00te : It's pretty big ... almost 4MB on a 32-bit platform, and 8MB on a 64-bit platform ... I'm not sure what the default Win32 stack-allocation is, but I don't think it's 4MB per-process unless you specifically request that.  On Linux 64-bit I believe that 8MB is the default limit.